# Google Chrome Extension in Flex

Tags: flash, google-chrome

Google have added Extensions API for Chrome. Now it's possible to write extensions using HTML/CSS/JS. I was trying to embed SWF in html page and communicate with this page, but I got:

> SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation:
>   ExternalInterface caller
>   chrome-extension://ilnamifbpeaokmlgefmainkehgpoppkj/main.swf
>   cannot access
>   chrome-extension://ilnamifbpeaokmlgefmainkehgpoppkj/options.html.

Is there way to allow SWF access extension HTML page? They are in same "domain".

I would appreciate it if someone could help.

Answer (score 4):

It may not be possible to communicate between SWF and the extension's HTML page. The problem is that in Chrome the Flash plugin cannot be sandboxed due to its requirements for resource access. So even though they are in the same domain, the SWF is outside of the sandbox that the extension's HTML page renders in. Hence the error. I'm not sure if this is as designed. You may want to file a bug in [the Chromium issue tracker](http://crbug.com).