# SWF sandbox violation Error #2060 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, google-chrome, flash

I am embedding a SWF object from a CDN into a page using [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation).

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = { allowscriptaccess: "always"};
window.swfobject.embedSWF(self.options.img_url+'/click2call.swf', "ISC2C_SwfContainer", "1", "1", "9.0.0", flashvars, params);
```

However, when I load the page in Chrome, I get this error:

> SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation:
>   ExternalInterface caller http://cdn.url/SWFObject.swf cannot access
>   https://na1.salesforce.com/00Q/o.     at
>   flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_evalJS()  at
>   flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()     at SWFObject/initApp()  at
>   SWFObject/___swfobject_Application1_applicationComplete()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()... error continues for a
>   while.

I read that this error can be solved by the AllowScriptAccess flag so I added that.

I also read in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817339/google-chrome-extension-in-flex) it seems to be a bug with Chrome that the Chrome Flash plugin cannot be sandboxed? - [sandbox bug answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817339/google-chrome-extension-in-flex)

This seems to be true as I was able to embed, load and use the object successfully in Firefox.

I have the Security.allowDomain("*") set as mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698506/actionscripts-externalinterface-addcallback-only-working-locally-not-in-produc). I don't have the Security.allowInsecureDomain set.

Is there a way to fix this error in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little late, but I've been having a similar issue lately. Could you let me know if you're running the HTML page using a file:// scheme or a chrome-extension:// scheme?

If that's the case, then flash will not let you invoke ExternalInterface.call() or ExternalInterface.addCallback(). Your page will have to be loaded through an HTTP server either locally or on a remote host. It's not just the location of the SWF file that matters, but the location of the container page that embeds the SWF file too (actually I'm not sure if flash checks the real location of the SWF file at all to be honest, but it definitely is checking the container page's location).

So to summarize, these will not work:

```
file:///C:/Local/Folder/page.html
chrome-extension://<extension_id>/page.html
```

where these will work:

```
http://subdomain.domain/page.html
https://subdomain.domain/page.html
```

EDIT: If you really want to be using the file:// or chrome-extension:// schemes or similar local schemes, then I'd suggest that you add the path to the SWF file or a path above it in the hierarchy to the Global Security Settings page here:

```
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html
```